# Get classname number between brackets from getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementsbyclassname

In my example, I want to know which number (between the square bracket) the classname has that was clicked on. This is necessary to write to the same class number of another div.

```
<div class="button_minus"></div>
<div class="input_test"></div>
<div class="button_minus"></div>
<div class="input_test"></div>
<div class="button_minus"></div>
<div class="input_test"></div>


$(".button_minus").click(function(){
            document.getElementsByClassname("input_test").[???].value = "test";
});
```

There is an option to give each "button_minus" a value parameter that can be given in the square brackets of the "input_test" but that seems not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

From the clicked element, you can navigate to its `.next()` element to get to the associated `input_test` div:

```js
$(".button_minus").click(function(){
  $(this).next().text('test');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button_minus">-</div>
<div class="input_test">input</div>
<div class="button_minus">-</div>
<div class="input_test">input</div>
<div class="button_minus">-</div>
<div class="input_test">input</div>
```

Note that because the element is a `<div>`, not an input-like field, don't use `.value` (or `.val()`) - use `textContent` or `.text()`.

If you need the index as well, check its index in a collection:

```js
const minuses = $(".button_minus");
minuses.click(function(){
  $(this).next().text('test');
  console.log(minuses.index(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button_minus">-</div>
<div class="input_test">input</div>
<div class="button_minus">-</div>
<div class="input_test">input</div>
<div class="button_minus">-</div>
<div class="input_test">input</div>
```

Comment: Okey thanks, but what if I want to know the number of the selected class?

Comment: Call `.index` on a collection of the minuses